# Strange behavior in R dataframe regarding rownames

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data.frame, if I use the head command, one of them hide its rownames.

This is Okay, I can see the rownames of it:

```
  > rownames(head(countData1))
  [1] "FBgn0000003" "FBgn0000008" "FBgn0000014" "FBgn0000015" "FBgn0000017"
  [6] "FBgn0000018"
```

this data.frame hide its rownames:

```
 > rownames(head(countData))
 [1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6"
```

But if I look only for rownames it appers:

```
 head (rownames(countData))
[1] "NONMMUT000003" "NONMMUT000005" "NONMMUT000011" "NONMMUT000020"
[5] "NONMMUT000022" "NONMMUT000024"

 > head (rownames(countData1))
 [1] "FBgn0000003" "FBgn0000008" "FBgn0000014" "FBgn0000015" "FBgn0000017"
 [6] "FBgn0000018"
```

The problem is that when going to downstream analysis the rownames on the countData data.frame get set to NULL.

```
 > dds
class: DESeqDataSet 
dim: 40699 10 
exptData(0):
assays(1): counts
**rownames: NULL**
rowRanges metadata column names(0):
colnames(10): 1 2 ... 9 10
colData names(3): sampleNames condition type
```

Someone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Solved my question. This issue was due a incompatibility of classes.

Using as.data.frame(countData) solved the problem.